# Как избавиться от синей верхней полоски в гугл карте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, карты

Есть фрейм, сделанный с помощью конструктора гугл карты с метками на нем - [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/wbmcg04v/)

```css
.i4ewOd-pzNkMb-haAclf.QUIbkc {
  display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1s9NO_idzOy6bV9e6jiSILCBdLOk" width="100%" height="420"></iframe>
```

При вставке его на сайт мне мешает верхняя синяя полоска, которая идет по умолчанию, как можно от нее избавиться или скрыть? 
`display:none!important;` блока и вставка во фрейм `frameborder="0" и style="border:0"` не спасает

Comment: Тут смотрели? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: что именно? там было написано про вставку `frameborder="0" и style="border:0"` в тело фрейма, но не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
.container-iframe{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #555;   
}
.container-iframe > iframe{  
  border: none;  
  margin-top: -46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-iframe">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1s9NO_idzOy6bV9e6jiSILCBdLOk" width="100%" height="420"></iframe>
</div>
```